# Moving a child from one parent to another in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parent-child

I would like to be able to change an elements parent. Basically I would like to move an element from one parent to another. I would like this to happen in Javascript, preferably using only the JQuery library.

Before code:

```
<div id = "div1">
  <p id = "paragraph">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing pellentesque egestas.
  </p>
</div> 
<div id = "div2></div>
```

After code:

```
<div id = "div1"> </div> 
<div id = "div2>
  <p id = "paragraph">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing pellentesque egestas.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: appendChild..... or append() if jQuery

Comment: What research have you done? This should be an easy web search

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
var block = document.querySelector('.block');
var parentNode = document.querySelector('#parent');
parentNode.insertBefore(block, parentNode.firstChild);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#paragraph').appendTo('#div2')
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('#div2').append('#paragraph');`
Should do it!

Just a little side note:
Use `.append()` when you add the element as the last children of the parent(#div2).
If you want it as the first you can use `.prepend()`

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla Javascript... A very basic example of how this could be done:

Define the elements paragraph and div2 as variables...

Create a new p element to move the textContent to in the div you are moving to...

Append the p element to the div you are moving to, then assign the textContent of the paragraph to the new p element.

Remove the initial p element from the initial div1

```js
// get the element of id paragraph
let target = document.getElementById('paragraph');
// get the element you wish to move it to
let div2 = document.getElementById('div2');

// a button to illustrate moving it from one element to another
let button = document.getElementById('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // create a new p tag to append the element to
  let p = document.createElement('p');
  // append the new p tag to the div2 element
  div2.append(p);
  // assign the targets textContent to the new p element
  p.textContent = target.textContent;
  // remove the old p element from the initial div
  target.remove();
  button.remove();
})
```

```css
#div1 {
background: #ddd;
}

#div2 {
background: #ff0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="div1"><span>This is Div 1</span>
    <p id="paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing pellentesque egestas.</p>
  </div>
  <input type="button" id="button" value="Click to move element">

  <div id="div2"><span>This is Div 2</span>
</div>
```

***Jquery:***

```js
let para = $('#paragraph');
let div2 = $('#div2');

let btn = $('#button');

btn.click(function(){
  let el = $('<p></p>');
  div2.append(el);
  el.text(para.text());
  $('#div1').children()[1].remove();
  btn.remove();
})
```

```css
#div1 {
background: #ddd;
}

#div2 {
background: #ff0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="div1"><span>This is Div 1</span>
    <p id="paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing pellentesque egestas.</p>
  </div>
  <input type="button" id="button" value="Click to move element">

  <div id="div2"><span>This is Div 2</span>
</div>
```